# расположение текста на кнопке

Tags: java, swing, gui

Имеется кнопка (экземпляр JButton). На данной кнопке установлено изображение ImageIcon и поверх этого изображения выводится текст. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы изображение располагалось посередине кнопки, а текст в нижней её части. Пробовал установить положение кнопки таким образом:

```
button.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM);
```

В результате текст располагается в нижней части кнопки, но при этом изображение на кнопке смещается вверх так, что его половина не видна. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить мою задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема легко решается с помощью метода класса `JButton` - [setIconTextGap(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIconTextGap-int-), который определяет расстояние между изображением кнопки и текстом на ней. Метод может принимать отрицательные значения. Свою проблему решил так: после вызовов методов `setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM)` и `setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER)` вызвал метод `setIconTextGap(int)` передав ему отрицательное значение и в результате получилось что текст располагался на самой иконке в нижней её части.